About $(\frac{a,1-a}{k})\cong\mathrm{M}_2(k).$
$k$ is a field.
A quaternion algebra over $k$ is a $4$-dimensional $k$-algebra with a basis $1,i,j,ij$ with the following multiplicative relations: $i^2\in k^\times, j\in k^\times, ij=-ji$ and every $c\in k$ commutes with $i$ and $j$. When $i^2=a,j^2=b$ this ring is denoted by $(\frac{a,b}{k}).$ Now, I want to do $$(\frac{a,1-a}{k})\cong\mathrm{M}_2(k).$$
I found an answer as follow:
Consider $z=1+i+j$. Then $z\cdot(1-i-j)=0$, the algerba is split.
I wonder that what is the definition of ''split'', and why this arguement gives the isomorphism? Thank you!

For the definition of a split $K$-algebra see this post. For the isomorphism, see this duplicate.

I see in the second link, they mention a property that $(\frac{a,b}{k})$ is split if and only if the norm of $(\frac{a,b}{k})$, $N:(\frac{a,b}{k})\rightarrow k$ has a non-trivial zero. Since we prove that $1+i+j$ is an non-trivial zero of norm map, thus is isomorphic to $\mathrm{M}_2(k)$. Is my explanation correct?

Any quaternion algebra/k is either split (isomorphic to M_2(k)) or division.  So once you exhibit a zero divisor, it must be split.

I wonder why the existence of zero divisors imples split.
